# Canvas only being displayed on the first image of the slider or connected to the bottom of each image

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So I tried to make it so that whenever an image is clicked it will draw a circle on a canvas. The image and the canvas are suppose to overlay. However, I have a problem when I have
`cnvs.style.position = 'absolute';` active all of my canvas' are stacked on each other on the first image. So if I were to click other images the circle would be drawn on the first image but not on the image clicked.  However, if I comment out `cnvs.style.position = 'absolute';` the canvas is being connected to the bottom of the image instead of being overlaid. I need to make it so that each canvas and image are overlaid so that when one image is clicked a circle will appear. I'm thinking I have a css problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```js
document.body.onload = addElement;

      function addElement() {
            
            // image path
            const imagePath = ['https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F8%2F84%2FAssociation_of_Gay_and_Lesbian_Psychiatrists_logo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fnewsgraphics%2F2016%2F07%2F14%2Fpluto-one-year%2Fassets%2Ficon-pluto.png&f=1&nofb=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.oFxADNN67dYP-ke5xg7HbQHaHG%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glassdoor.com%2Fsqll%2F1065746%2Felevation-church-squarelogo-1453223965790.png&f=1&nofb=1'];
            
            for (const image of imagePath) {
                  // get the item id of an image
                  var slice = image.slice(26, 34);
                  var id = image;
                  var hdnName = document.getElementById("sendServ"); 

                  const img = document.createElement("img");
                  img.src = image;
                  img.classList.add("new");
                  img.id = slice;

                  const cnvs = document.createElement("canvas");
                  cnvs.classList.add("suiteiCanvas");
                 
                 // cnvs.style.position = 'absolute';
                  cnvs.style.left = img.offsetLeft + "px";
                  cnvs.style.top = img.offsetTop + "px";
                  cnvs.style.display = 'none';

                  var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
                  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                  ctx.lineWidth = 15;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
                  ctx.stroke();

                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
                  div.id = id;
                  div1.id = '1';
                  div.classList.add("image");


                  img.onclick = function draw() {
                        cnvs.style.display = '';
                        hdnName.value = img.id;
                  };

                  cnvs.onclick = function remove() {
                        cnvs.style.display = 'none';
                        hdnName.value = null;
                  };

                  document.getElementById('suitei-slider').appendChild(div);
               
                  document.getElementById(image).appendChild(img);
                  document.getElementById(image).appendChild(cnvs);
               
               
            }
      }
      
// slick slider
```

```css
canvas.suiteiCanvas{
  height: auto; 
  width: auto;
  
max-height: 200px;
max-width: 150px;

margin-left: 100px; 
margin-right: 100px;
border:3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
}

#draw-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 16px 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

img.new {
 
 
  height: auto; 
  width: auto;

max-height: 200px;
max-width: 150px;

margin-left: 100px; 
margin-right: 100px;
border:3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-items" id="suitei-slider"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="sendServ">
```

Comment: There is an error in your snippet, same as in your previous post, `unexpected token <`, because of this: `const imagePath = <?= json_encode($face) ?>;`, so we cannot run it

Comment: So I just made a dummy array for imagePath. It should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your canvases in `position: absolute` inside a container in `position: relative` so that your canvases are still contained in the container. Since the containers are not in `position: absolute`, they don't overlay, but their content will, so your canvases will overlay with the images.

Then, you have to center you canvases (I suspect), so I set the canvases dimensions (for now it's hard coded) and fixed the `x` position of the circle.

I hope it is what you were looking for.

```js
document.body.onload = addElement;

      function addElement() {
            
            // image path
            const imagePath = ['https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F8%2F84%2FAssociation_of_Gay_and_Lesbian_Psychiatrists_logo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fnewsgraphics%2F2016%2F07%2F14%2Fpluto-one-year%2Fassets%2Ficon-pluto.png&f=1&nofb=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.oFxADNN67dYP-ke5xg7HbQHaHG%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glassdoor.com%2Fsqll%2F1065746%2Felevation-church-squarelogo-1453223965790.png&f=1&nofb=1'];
            
            for (const image of imagePath) {
                  // get the item id of an image
                  var slice = image.slice(26, 34);
                  var id = image;
                  var hdnName = document.getElementById("sendServ"); 

                  const img = document.createElement("img");
                  img.src = image;
                  img.classList.add("new");
                  img.id = slice;

                  const cnvs = document.createElement("canvas");
                  cnvs.classList.add("suiteiCanvas");
                 
                 // cnvs.style.position = 'absolute';
                  cnvs.style.left = img.offsetLeft + "px";
                  cnvs.style.top = img.offsetTop + "px";
                  cnvs.style.display = 'none';
                  cnvs.width = 150;
                  cnvs.height = 150;

                  var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
                  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                  ctx.lineWidth = 15;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
                  ctx.stroke();

                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
                  div.id = id;
                  div1.id = '1';
                  div.classList.add("image");


                  img.onclick = function draw() {
                        cnvs.style.display = '';
                        hdnName.value = img.id;
                  };

                  cnvs.onclick = function remove() {
                        cnvs.style.display = 'none';
                        hdnName.value = null;
                  };

                  document.getElementById('suitei-slider').appendChild(div);
               
                  document.getElementById(image).appendChild(img);
                  document.getElementById(image).appendChild(cnvs);
               
               
            }
      }
      
// slick slider
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative; /* add this */
  user-select: none; /* and this maybe */
}

canvas.suiteiCanvas{
  height: auto; 
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  /*margin-left: 100px; 
  margin-right: 100px;*/
  border:3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
  position: absolute; /* add this */
}

#draw-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 16px 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

img.new { 
  height: auto; 
  width: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 150px;
  /*margin-left: 100px; 
  margin-right: 100px;*/
  border:3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-items" id="suitei-slider"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="sendServ">
```

Comment: I added this `.image { ...; user-select: none; }`, it prevents the images to be selected and to appear in blue when you click several times. I thought that it may be useful.

Comment: So that essentially did what I was trying to do. However it just starts to act strange when I'm using slick slider as well. I have an image that kind of shows what I mean https://imgur.com/a/PHkCS74

Comment: I decided to remove the slider from my snippet because it is quit a struggle to get it to work on the snippet I think. I would of had to added the CDN for jquery and slick slider and css styling sheets.

Comment: Ah, I got it to work. I forgot to remove my margin from my img css as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wonder what each line means here it is a more clean code and with comments on many lines... for my understanding you code is a little confuse. You should use more times functions to be more readable, etc.

```js
let index = 0;
const display = "table"; // or "grid" if horizontal, but this migh depend where you place the rest of the code, cause i added the style to the body
const x = 0;
const y = 0;
const images = {
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  url: [
    'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F8%2F84%2FAssociation_of_Gay_and_Lesbian_Psychiatrists_logo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1',
    'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fnewsgraphics%2F2016%2F07%2F14%2Fpluto-one-year%2Fassets%2Ficon-pluto.png&f=1&nofb=1',
    'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.oFxADNN67dYP-ke5xg7HbQHaHG%26pid%3DApi&f=1',
    'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glassdoor.com%2Fsqll%2F1065746%2Felevation-church-squarelogo-1453223965790.png&f=1&nofb=1'
  ]
}

function createHTML() {
  console.log('E: Execute & R: Request & I: Informative');
  //loop to go true all images
  document.body.style.display = display;
  for (const image of images.url) {
    //each image will correspond to a canvas element
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //each canvas element will has is own properties (in this case all the same)
    canvas.id = 'option' + [index];
    canvas.height = images.height;
    canvas.width = images.width;
    canvas.style.padding = '10px';

    //function to get the corresponded image of that particular canvas element
    drawImages(canvas);

    //add an event listener for when a user click on the particular canvas
    canvas.addEventListener("click", optionClick, false);

    //all html part was handle we can append it to the body
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    index++;
  }
}

function drawImages(canvas) {
  //we need to use the getContext canvas function to draw anything inside the canvas element
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const background = new Image();

  //This is needed because if the drawImage is called from a different place that the createHTML function
  //index value will not be at 0 and it will for sure with an heigher id that the one expected
  //so we are using regex to remove all letters from the canvas.id and get the number to use it later
  index = canvas.id.replace(/\D/g, '');

  //console.log('E: Drawing image ' + index + ' on canvas ' + canvas.id);

  //get the image url using the index to get the corresponded image
  background.src = images.url[index];
  //no idea why but to place the image, we need to use the onload event
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage
  background.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
}

function drawX(canvas) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  console.log('E: Placing X on canvas ' + canvas.id);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(images.width, images.height);
  ctx.moveTo(images.height, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, images.width);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function clear(canvas) {
  console.log('E: clearing canvas ' + canvas.id);

  canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  drawImages(canvas);
}

function optionClick(e) {
  log = true;
  const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
  for (const option of canvas) {
    if (log) console.log('I: User clicked at option ' + e.target.id + ':' + option.id);
    log = false;
    if (e.target.id === option.id) {
      console.log('R: Drawing request at canvas ' + option.id);
      drawX(option);
    } else {
      console.log('R: Clearing request at canvas ' + option.id);
      clear(option);
    }
  }
}

//We start by calling createHTML (that will handle with all HTML elements)
window.onload = createHTML;
```

```css
canvas.suiteiCanvas {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;

  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 150px;

  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
}

#draw-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 16px 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

img.new {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;

  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 150px;

  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);

}
```

```html
<body></body>
```